# Error conecting raspberry with my arduino in a serial port

Tags: arduino-uno, raspberrypi

Hi i am trying to make a comunication between theses device but when i am trying to run in my raspberry i have the follow error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "serial.py", line 1, in 
>       import serial
>     File "/home/pi/Desktop/serial.py", line 2, in 
>       ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Serial'

i have the next code:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

while 1:

    if(ser.in_waiting >0):
        line = ser.readline()
        print(line)
```

If any can help me, i will be thankfull

Comment: did you check if a function nsmed `Serial` actually exists in the serial library?

Comment: Don't name your files with the [names of modules you're using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at). Also, why ask a Raspberry question on Arduino site when we have RPi.SE, where the exact same question was already [answered](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/74742/python-serial-serial-module-not-found-error)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's almost certainly happening here is that you've named your file `serial.py`, so the import is trying to load the library from your file within the current working directory.

To fix this problem, simply rename your `serial.py` script to something else, for example `serial_comms.py` or whatever other useful name you want.

Comment: you are a genius, that was the problem thank you

Comment: @JesusMiguelHerrera You're most welcome. I ran into this when I had to learn Python for a previous job.